# Reverse decode function of c-struct in Python

Tags: python, c, hid

I am using this function found on GitHub to read some data from a HID-stream in Python. h.read(64)

```
def decode_bytes(byte_1, byte_2, byte_3, byte_4):
    bytes_reversed_and_concatenated = byte_4 * (16 ** 6) + byte_3 * (16 ** 4) + byte_2 * (16 ** 2) + byte_1

    bytes_hex = hex(bytes_reversed_and_concatenated)[2:]

    bytes_decimal = str(round(struct.unpack('!f', bytes.fromhex(bytes_hex))[0], 1))

    return bytes_decimal
```

The function converts four bytes (in hex-values as integers) from the stream to a Python float-value which is returned as a string. I've read that a C-struct float representation takes up four bytes, so I guess that explains that the function takes four bytes as an input. But apart from that, I'm pretty blank as to how and why the function works.

I have two questions:

First I would very much like to get a better understanding of how the function works. Why does it reverse the byte order and what is up with the 16 ** 6, 16 ** 4 and so on? I am having a hard time figuring out, what that does in Python.

Second I would like to reverse the function. Meaning I would like to be able to supply a float as an input and get out a list of four integer-hex-values, which I can write back via the HID-interface. But I have no idea, where to start.

I was hoping to get some pointers in the right direction. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That is way more code than it needs to be. Most of it could be replaced by `struct.unpack('<f', bytes([byte_1, byte_2, byte_3, byte_4]))`, and the rest of it probably shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: Don't use this code as an example of what to write. It's terrible code.

Comment: Shifting bytes using math is weird. But I like it. Each line of code like special kind of modern art :D

Answer (score 0):

So the comment from @user2357112 helped me figure everything out. The working and much simpler function now looks like this:

```
def decode_bytes(byte_1, byte_2, byte_3, byte_4):

    return_value = struct.unpack('<f', bytes([byte_1, byte_2, byte_3, byte_4]))
    return str(round(return_value[0], 1))
```

And if I want to wrap a float back up as a bytes array I do this:

```
struct.pack('<f', float(float_value))
```

Also I learned a bit about Endianness along the way. Thanks.